# Loop over multidimensional NumPy fileArray in R

Tags: r, numpy, for-loop, multidimensional-array, reticulate

I´m new to R and have problems to generate a for loop: 
I have a multidimensional array (NumPy File) in R and would like to automate the request of the part of the array. My array has a shape of (500, 192). I would like to plot a graph for Sample 1, 2 ... until sample 500.

AP has the structure: 
num [1:500, 1:192] 0.0323 0.0532 0.0135 0.0474 0.2026 ...

AP.shap has the structure:
num [1:192] 3.23e-02 4.88e-04 1.39e-03 7.49e-04 5.82e-05 ...

```
library(reticulate)
library(RcppCNPy)
library(ggplot2)

#Sample 1
AP.shap <- (AP[1 ,]) # Sample 1

# convert to dataframe
typeof(AP.shap) # type double
AP.shap <- as.data.frame(AP.shap)
typeof(AP.shap) # list

# New Column with Nrow
AP.shap$Hour <- seq.int(nrow(AP.shap))

columnnames <- c("Shap", "Hour")

colnames(AP.shap) <- columnnames 

#Plot
ggplot(AP.shap, aes(Hour, Shap))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + theme_minimal() + 
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Hours of Sample 1 - Air Pressure - G_PM"[1], " - All Season"))) + 
  xlab("Hour") +
  ylab("Shap Value") +
  ggsave("1_Hour_AP_G_allseason.png", plot = last_plot(), device = "png", path = "xy")
```

The next one would be:

```
#Sample 2
AP.shap <- (AP[**2** ,]) # Sample 1

# convert to dataframe
typeof(AP.shap) # type double
AP.shap <- as.data.frame(AP.shap)
typeof(AP.shap) # list

# New Column with Nrow
AP.shap$Hour <- seq.int(nrow(AP.shap))
columnnames <- c("Shap", "Hour")
colnames(AP.shap) <- columnnames 

#Plot
ggplot(AP.shap, aes(Hour, Shap))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + theme_minimal() + 
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Hours of Sample **2** - Air Pressure - G_PM"[1], " - All Season"))) + 
  xlab("Hour") +
  ylab("Shap Value") +
  ggsave("**2**_Hour_AP_G_allseason.png", plot = last_plot(), device = "png", path = "xy")
```

[image: Graph Sample 1]

Comment: Did you attempt your loop? Please show attempt and describe any errors/undesired results. Also, for a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451), please show the origins of *AP.shap* and its assignment in code.

Comment: Note: you can save [Numpy arrays as text](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html) and read into R without any `reticulate` or other Python API.

Comment: I didn´t attempt my loop becauce I don´t have an approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply generalize your process into a user-defined method that receives a number as input parameter since this is the only item that changes. Have that parameter slice data for sample and pass into titles and file names. See below where `num` is used.

Then, call it iteratively with `for`, `while`, or `lapply` which latter can store plot objects to a list for continued use later.

```
build_plot <- function(num) {

   # Sample by num
   AP.shap <- (AP[num, ]) # Sample num

   # convert to dataframe
   AP.shap <- as.data.frame(AP.shap)
   # New Column with Nrow
   AP.shap$Hour <- seq.int(nrow(AP.shap))
   colnames(AP.shap) <-  c("Shap", "Hour")

   # Plot
   p <- ggplot(AP.shap, aes(Hour, Shap)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity") + theme_minimal() + 
          ggtitle(expression(paste("Hours of Sample", num, 
                                   "- Air Pressure - G_PM"[1], " - All Season"))) + 
          xlab("Hour") + ylab("Shap Value")

   # Save 
   ggsave(paste0(num, "_Hour_AP_G_allseason.png"), plot = p, device = "png", path = "xy")

   return(p)    
}

# SAVES EACH PLOT FILE AND STORES PLOT TO R LIST
plot_list <- lapply(seq(1, 500), build_plot)

# INTERACTIVELY DISPLAY PLOT
plot_list[[1]]
plot_list[[2]]
plot_list[[3]]
```

---

For traditional looping, see `for` and `while` approaches that do not store objects to an R list. Note: be cautious of printing 500 plots in your environment. Remove `print()` to simply save plots to file.

```
# SAVES EACH PLOT FILE AND DISPLAYS PLOT TO SCREEN
for (i in seq(1, 500)) {
   print(build_plot(i))
}

i = 1
# SAVES EACH PLOT FILE AND DISPLAYS PLOT TO SCREEN
while(i <= 500) {
   print(build_plot(i))
   i = i + 1
}
```